# How SpriteKit SKAction runBlock: can affect FPS performance?

Tags: ios, performance, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, skaction

I'm using SKAction category to play AVAudioPlayer sounds - it looks like this:

```
+ (SKAction *)atw_playSoundWithData:(NSData *)soundData {
    // If AVAudioSession is inactive do not make any sound
    if ([BAPAppDelegate isAudioSessionActive] == NO) {
        return [SKAction runBlock:^{}];
    } else {
        // Create playSoundAction which starts on concurrent queue to gain speed
        return [SKAction runBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:&error];

            if (!error) {
                audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
                [audioPlayer play];

                // Cache audioPlayer to avoid autoreleasing before play end
                [SKAction atw_cacheAudioPlayer:audioPlayer];
            }
           //NSLog(@"%s  Added: %@ withError: %@, Cache: %lu", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, audioPlayer, error, (unsigned long)[sATWAudioPlayersCache count]);
        } queue:sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue];
    }
}
```

Caching AVAudioPlayer is done to avoid premature player releasing - here is the method:

```
static NSMutableSet *sATWAudioPlayersCache; // It's our cache
static dispatch_queue_t sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue; // It's our concurrent queue of audioPlayers that are playing
+ (void)atw_cacheAudioPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer {

    // Init cache for the first time
    if (sATWAudioPlayersCache == nil) {
        sATWAudioPlayersCache = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.AppThatWorks.SKAction+ATWSound.sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    }

    if (audioPlayer == nil) return;

    dispatch_barrier_async(sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue, ^{
        [sATWAudioPlayersCache addObject:audioPlayer];
    });

    // Set delayed cache clear event for that audioPlayer (with barrier also to ensure exclusive access)
    double delay = [audioPlayer duration]+0.1; // +0.1 second buffer for safe sound end
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue, ^(void){
        dispatch_barrier_async(sATWAudioPlayersCacheQueue, ^{
            // For safety sake, stop audioPlayer to avoid potential bad access while removing/autoreleasing.
            // It could happen if delay was nearly equal to [audioPlayer duration] (i.e. released while stopping).
            [audioPlayer stop];
            [sATWAudioPlayersCache removeObject:audioPlayer];
            //NSLog(@"%s Removed: %@ , Cache: %lu", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, audioPlayer, (unsigned long)[sATWAudioPlayersCache count]);
        });
    });
}
```

I've found that playing circa 10 sounds per second this way affects FPS from 60 to sometimes even 49 fps (unfortunately, its quite visible), although CPU stays still at 20% of its utilisation. Because skipping playing sounds fixes FPS performance, that's why my question comes from:

**Question:** *How SKAction runBlock: can affect FPS? (or how my GCD solution/AVAudioPlayer can do that?)*

Comment: have you tried without dispatch async? in any case you'll do much better for many simultaneous sounds by using a "proper" openal audio engine, specifically objectal

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is completely right about using a proper audio engine. I can't recommend objectal enough; it will save you a lot of time, very easy to use, great performance.

Comment: Thx! I'll give it a try but I don't feel comfortable with changing this without understanding the point: why CPU gets bored during playing but FPS gets a hit (and what the heck AVAudioPlayer can have to do with it). Changing to serial queue have lessen the pain, although I don't get it too.

Comment: fps is an average, and cpu % is most likely one too. So if a single frame takes 100% but then next ten don't you still get crappy performance with relatively good fps or CPU %. If you want precise timings, use Instruments.